# Excel VBA - collect, modify and paste data to worksheet using class module and dictionary

Tags: vba, class, excel, properties

With the help of Tim and Paul below the code now works. I think it is useful and may help others learn how to use class modules, so have updated the code to a working version and left it on the site. It gets a table from an Excel sheet, loads the data into an array in a class module, gets array members, changes the members and updates the worksheet table. Easier to use than arrays.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0


Dim myArray As Variant
Public dID, dPARAM
Public DATA As Variant

Sub GET_DATA(TBL As String)
Dim WS As String

    WS = Names(TBL).RefersToRange.Parent.NAME
    DATA = Worksheets(WS).Range(TBL).CurrentRegion.Value
End Sub

Property Get TESTARRAY() As Variant
TESTARRAY = myArray
End Property

Property Let TESTARRAY(DATA As Variant)
 myArray = DATA
End Property

Function INIT(TBL As String)
    Call GET_DATA(TBL)
    TESTARRAY = DATA
End Function


Function NO_IDS()
NO_IDS = dID.Count
End Function


Function IDS(TBL As String)
Dim ROW As Integer, COL As Integer
Dim Test As Boolean
Set dID = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dPARAM = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim VAL As Variant

Call GET_DATA(TBL)

'save array members
For ROW = LBound(DATA, 1) To UBound(DATA, 1)
    dID.ADD Item:=CStr(ROW), KEY:=CStr(DATA(ROW, 1))
Next ROW

For COL = LBound(DATA, 2) To UBound(DATA, 2)
    dPARAM.ADD Item:=CStr(COL), KEY:=CStr(DATA(1, COL))
Next COL

End Function


Function UPDATE_MTX(TBL As String)
Dim RESULT As Variant
Dim WS As String
Dim RNGE As Range, RNGE_ADD As String
Dim ROW As Integer, COL As Integer

On Error GoTo TRAP_ERR:

RESULT = myArray
WS = Names(TBL).RefersToRange.Parent.NAME
ROW = Worksheets(WS).Range(TBL).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
COL = Worksheets(WS).Range(TBL).CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
Set RNGE = Worksheets(WS).Range(TBL).Resize(ROW, COL)
RNGE_ADD = RNGE.Address


RNGE.Value = RESULT

TRAP_ERR:
MsgBox "ERROR FOUND"

End Function


Function CHANGE_MTX(ID As String, PARAM As String, VAL As Variant)
Dim ROW As Integer
Dim COL As Integer

If dID.exists(ID) And dPARAM.exists(PARAM) Then
    ROW = CInt(dID(ID))
    COL = CInt(dPARAM(PARAM))
    myArray(ROW, COL) = VAL
Else
    CHANGE_MTX = "FAIL"
End If

End Function

Function GET_VAL(ID As String, PARAM As String)
Dim ROW As Integer
Dim COL As Integer


If dID.exists(ID) And dPARAM.exists(PARAM) Then
    ROW = CInt(dID(ID))
    COL = CInt(dPARAM(PARAM))
    GET_VAL = myArray(ROW, COL)
    Exit Function
Else
    GET_VAL = "FAIL"
End If

End Function



'test code in a module
 Sub testcls()

 Dim Test As New clsTABLE
 Dim VAL As Variant

 Test.IDS ("tbl_TEST")
 Test.INIT ("tbl_TEST")
 VAL = Test.GET_VAL("10", "E")
 Call Test.CHANGE_MTX("10", "E", "xxx")

 Call Test.UPDATE_MTX("tbl_TEST")

 End Sub
```

Comment: `ROW = Worksheets(WS).Range(TBL).CurrentRegion.ROWS.Count` - did you copy/paste this directly from the editor? `ROWS` shouldn't be capitalized like that...

Comment: Yes, and I've checked again...``ROWS`` is still in caps

Comment: I've added all the code in case it helps. Tim, the use of a dictionary for row and col headings comes from previous question you answered.

Comment: `Property Let sArray(Optional rIndex As Integer, Optional cindex As Integer, inArray As Variant)`  - optional arguments should always come *last* in the parameter list.

Comment: I agree, but if i move the ``inArray as variant`` to the front I get a compile error. Since I don't use the index properties (I use the ``Get_Val`` fn instead) how can I modify the ``Let`` and ``Get`` property statements?

Comment: something like this? 
``Property Get sArray() As Variant
sArray = myArray
End Property


Property Let sArray(ByRef DATA() As Variant)
 myArray = sArray
End Property``

Comment: I think you are right that ``ROWS`` should be in lower case and could be the reason excel is crashing. I don't have any variables named ``ROWS`` so do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: The code works on a slower machine, could speed be a problem? There is also a DDE feed running in the background.

Comment: ROWS is capitalized because there IS a variable named "ROWS" in your project (another module). You are using a lot of variables with names of Excel properties like "ROW", "NAME", "ADD", "KEY"; most likely these are causing conflicts. One way to find them is to search with these options: "Current Project" (not "Current Module"), "Find Whole Word Only", and "Match Case". This will eventually show your variables. Once identified you'll have to re-open the file and not let it compile ("Don't allow macros to run") then open the VBA editor, find and replace all your offending variable names (cont)

Comment: To verify that there are no more offending variable names you should be able to rename all Excel properties with proper case (first capital). For example if you do a Find-and-Replace (Current Project, Find Whole Word Only, and Match Case) for "ROWS" with "Rows" it will perform just one replacement, because Excel will convert all other property case replacements automatically. Only then you will have eliminated the issue completely

Comment: @Paul. I agree. I did that and didn't find any variables call ``ROWS``. To correct the case I created another public variable called ``Rows`` which then corrected code - see edited code above. I'm still getting an error on the  ``RNGE.value`` line.

Comment: what are the contents of inArray when entering the Property Let sArray()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86606/discussion-between-zeus-and-paul-bica).